# What is the base of the logarithm in Log Transformation in image processing?

Tags: image, image-processing

I am reading gonzales image processing book and as you know the log transformation has been defined like the following in the book:

```
s = c*log(1+r)
```

Now I have one question:
Is the logarithm based on 10 or it is a natural logarithm which is based on napier number?

Answer (score 2):

The log transform is used for dark pixels enhancement. The dark pixels in an image are expanded as compare to the higher pixel values. So the base can be any number depending on the visualization effect of image.

I think `log10` is often used because it is related to the decibel scale in signal processing, such as what is used in [signal to noise definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio#Definition).

Answer (score 1):

If this is [log()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log/) from `math.h`, then it's the natural logarithm.

That is, it's base is [e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29), which is approximately 2.71828.